# Find a cell/cell range with custom name in excel using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am having an excel with having custom name to certain cells. For example: vehicleCost for cell B5. I need to set values to these cells from the data that is sent by the UI. By using Apache POI in java I am able to get the cell by using the cell identifier like A1,A2 etc but not with the cell name. Below is the code I am using now. I thought of having a custom map with cell identifier and name and iterate it but my excel sheet is having too many data and it make the code clumsy. Kindly let me know how to fetch a cell by the cell name and thereby set a value to it in Apache POI.Thanks in advance

```
//Need to find a cell(B5) with name "VehicleCost"
CellReference cellReference = new CellReference("VehicleSheet!B5"); //Working
CellReference cellReference = new CellReference("VehicleSheet!VehicleCost") //Not working
Row row = mappingSheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow());
Cell cell = row.getCell(cellReference.getCol());
```

Comment: Why not use the built in API provided by Apache POI? https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#getName-java.lang.String-

Comment: @Gagravarr : Using the above api I can get the name object. But how to set a value for that particular cell ?

Comment: Get the name, then get the cell(s) for that name, then set them as usual